# How do I import data from a class C#

Tags: c#, linq, input, output

I have a question for you. I write the method correctly. I need to import data from a class . Sorting by age. And output only men.

Since method must then return the men sorted by their age

Comment: test is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code returns ordered names of all men in collection:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> OrderedMales(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    return persons.Where(p => p.Sex == Gender.Male).OrderBy(p => p.Name).Select(p => p.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the above was close, but you wanted sorted by age. Perhaps this might work?

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> OrderedMales(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    return persons.Where(
        p => p.Sex == Gender.Male).OrderBy(p => p.Age);
}
```